# ASP.NET and MySQL Connector Net

Tags: asp.net, mysql

I am using latest version of **MySQL connector Net** to connect to a MySQL database from an ASP.NET form. I have copied the files *MySql.Data.dll*, *MySql.Data.Entity.dll* and *MySql.Web.dll* in the **Bin** folder of my ASP.NET application. Also I have imported required libraries using these lines:

```
Imports MySql.Data
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
```

The image below shows the code and the error that I am getting:
[image]

What is wrong with the code please?

Comment: Why has this question made eligible for bounty, please?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a sample, this might help. [Click HERE](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/7331/connecting-to-a-mysql-database-using-aspnet) for example describes using ASP.NET/MySql.Data to connect to a MySQL Database.

Answer (score 0):

No idea where dataset came from, should be database=dbherpes.